# WELD-ENV-001004 warning when using Jetty 9

Tags: cdi, weld, jetty-9

In my project I use Jetty 9.2.5 + Weld 2.2.7 (currently the latest versions). When I startup Jetty this warning is displayed:

```
WARN: WELD-ENV-001004: Found both WEB-INF/beans.xml and WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/beans.xml. It's not portable to use both locations at the same time.
```

This is strange and not correct. There is no `WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/beans.xml` in the war file! Is this a bug or have i overlooked something?

Ready to run example project can be found on [github](https://github.com/rmuller/java8-examples/tree/master/jetty-maven-cdi)

Comment: I can't run this project using `mvn jetty:run` is there another way?

Comment: Should not be a problem. Check my updated README file with detailed instructions at https://github.com/rmuller/java8-examples/tree/master/jetty-maven-cdi

Comment: @John Ament. Probably found your problem, can you please try again?